# Prestashop override Shop class

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I override the Shop class and i put in `mymodule/override/classes`

```
class Shop extends ShopCore
{
   public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null)
   {
       parent::__construct($id, $id_lang, $id_shop);
   }

   public static function someMethod()
   {

   }

}
```

When i call `someMethod` in front controller i get the error :

> Call to undefined method Shop::someMethod()

Its possible in prestashop to add a static method to override class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation of the module should copy the **/mymodule/override/classes/Shop.php** to **/override/classes** but it doesnt.

The correct location of the override is in **/mymodule/override/classes/shop/Shop.php** instead of **/mymodule/override/classes/Shop.php**

Now the installation of module copies the file to the correct directory.